# Mac Keychain - remember svn+ssh// password

Tags: macos, svn, ssh, password-protection, keychain

I'm using Snow Leopard and I access svn through the standard commandline:

```
svn co svn+ssh//myusername@example.org/svn/myproject
```

How can I get Keychain / svn to remember my password?

Comment: What version of Subversion are you using?

Comment: svn --version returned:

svn, version 1.6.5 (r38866)
   compiled Jun 24 2010, 17:16:45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I seem to have this working by simply creating a keychain in KeyChain Access that matches my svn user name... ? can it be that simple?

I'll be curious to know if that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 1):

svn from version 1.4 onwards supports Keychain passwords, but perhaps there is something to do with svn+ssh that means they aren't being used in your case.
I recommend trying out a proper Mac OS X SVN client instead.

Versions:  http://versionsapp.com/
Cornerstone: http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but - if possible - I would like to stick to the tools bundled with my operating system. I hope to find out how to apply the Keychain support for svn+ssh.

Comment: Ah, that may be the issue.  I don't think the Apple build of Subversion supports the keychain correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SSH keys instead.  You'll find that once set up they're far easier to manage from the command line.

Check out [Subversion support and ssh key pairs](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/subversion-support-and-ssh-key-pairs/) for a quick tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to follow the tutorial, but unfortunately, I got stuck at the scp step:

scp: 03034: SCP access is denied 

Could I do that in another way? Note that I have Samba access to the server.